# C# List<T> indexer thread safety

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Until recently, I had been under the assumption that setting an element of a `List<T>` via indexer is thread safe in the following context.

```
// Assumes destination.Count >= source.Count
static void Function<T,U>(List<T> source, Func<T,U> converter, List<U> destination)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, source.Count), range =>
     {
         for(int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
         {
             destination[i] = converter(source[i]);
         }
     });
}
```

Since `List<T>` stores its elements in an array internally and setting one by index shouldn't necessitate resizing, this seemed like a reasonable leap of faith. Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs) of `List<T>` in .NET Core however, it appears that the indexer's setter modifies some internal state (see below).

```
// Sets or Gets the element at the given index.
public T this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        // Following trick can reduce the range check by one
        if ((uint)index >= (uint)_size)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException();
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        return _items[index];
    }

    set
    {
        if ((uint)index >= (uint)_size)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException();
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        _items[index] = value;
        _version++;
    }
}
```

So should I assume that `List<T>` is not thread-safe even when each thread is only getting/setting elements from its own portion of the collection?

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/). First thing you need to do is figure out what you need to be safe. As for the code you're looking at, I would say it's not thread-safe. And you certainly shouldn't assume anything not documented as thread-safe actually is. However, note that the `_version` field is used for an implementation detail you may not be concerned about. That it's modified unsafely may not matter to you.

Comment: If you want thread safety, take a look at [thread-safe collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Although you're not actually asking this, but it might be better to avoid modifying state within a parallel loop. If the situation is that `converter` is a long-running operation then it is best to compute the result using `Parallel` and then just assign the result with one thread. Try this: `static List<U> Function<T, U>(List<T> source, Func<T, U> converter) { return source.AsParallel().Select(s => converter(s)).ToList(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a read here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#Anchor_10

To answer your question, no - as per the documentation, it's not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Even if the *current* implementation appeared to be thread safe (which it doesn't, anyway), it would still be a bad idea to make that assumption. Since the documentation explicitly says it's not thread safe - future versions may legally change the underlying implementation to no longer be thread safe and break any assumption you previously relied on.